# How do I get 'getchar()' to not block the input?

Tags: c++, input

I am working on designing a pong like game but converting a `getchar()` to `getch()` and `getche()`, respectively, but `getchar()` is blocking the input. I am using C++ code, and while there *is* the ncurses library, I heard that this is a better approach; I am only needing to update this one command.

How do I get `getchar()` to not block the input?

The code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Prototypes
char inputReader();
void updateWorld();
void renderWorld();
void initTermios(int echo);
void resetTermios(void);
char getch_(int echo);
char getch(void);
char getche(void);

static struct termios oldChars, newChars;
int main()
{
   bool running = true;

   do
   {
      if(getche() == 'q')
      {
         running = false;
      }
      updateWorld();
      renderWorld();
   }

   while(running);
   std::cout << "I exited the loop";
   return 0;
}

char inputReader()
{
   return getch();
}

void updateWorld()
{
  std::cout << "I am updating the world" << std::endl;
}

void renderWorld() {}

void initTermios(int echo) //struct termios &oldChars, struct termios &newChars) 
{
  tcgetattr(0, &oldChars); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
  newChars = oldChars; /* make new settings same as old settings */
  newChars.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */
  newChars.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; /* set echo mode */
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &newChars); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void)//struct termios &oldChars)
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oldChars);
}

/* Read 1 character - echo defines echo mode */
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo); //oldChars, newChars);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();//oldChars);
  return ch;
}

/* Read 1 character without echo */
char getch(void) 
{
  return getch_(0);
}

/* Read 1 character with echo */
char getche(void) 
{
  return getch_(1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to GameDevSE! Just making note of my edits; You repeated yourself, in the body of your question, so I removed the redundancy for easier reading. I also removed code that we know to be unrelated to your problem (code that was commented out), to simplify your code. "Debug my code" questions have to present a minimal example to be on topic.

Comment: I will try to do better with it. Question where does fcntl command come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In initTermios() set file descriptor of standard input(that's the '0' parameter) to non-blocking behavior.

```
void initTermios(int echo) //struct termios &oldChars, struct termios &newChars)
{
  fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
  tcgetattr(0, &oldChars); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
  newChars = oldChars; /* make new settings same as old settings */
  newChars.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */
  newChars.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; /* set echo mode */
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &newChars); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}
```

Now console will react to your every key press, getchar won't block input.

Comment: I tried entering the fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) into the place you listed but now it is saying. main.cpp: In function ‘void initTermios(int)’:
main.cpp:83:12: error: ‘F_SETFL’ was not declared in this scope
   fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
            ^
main.cpp:83:21: error: ‘O_NONBLOCK’ was not declared in this scope
   fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
                     ^
main.cpp:83:31: error: ‘fcntl’ was not declared in this scope
   fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
                               ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1